# How to get the sum for a float numbers within a text file?

Tags: python

I'm newbie to python, I'm doing this exercise I have to extract numbers from specific lines within a file.

The Task is to Write a program that prompts for a file name, then opens that file and reads through the file, looking for lines of the form:
X-DSPAM-Confidence:    0.8475
Count these lines and extract the floating point values from each of the lines and compute the average of those values and produce an output as shown below.
You can download the sample data at http://www.pythonlearn.com/code/mbox-short.txt when you are testing below enter mbox-short.txt as the file name.

I have don't so far with the code and I need to get the total and the count to calculate the average :

http://i.gyazo.com/31373bdbc83c7f421236bc94d323d653.png

I should get this average result: **0.750718518519**

```
#Use the file name mbox-short.txt as the file name
fname = raw_input("Enter file name: ")
if len(fname) == 0:
    fname = 'file.txt'
fh = open(fname)
count = 0
total = 0
for line in fh:
    line = line.rstrip()
    if not line.startswith("For example    0.6545") : continue
    x = line[20:28]
    xx = float(x)
    count = count + 1

    print xx

    #average = total/count

    #print average

print "Done"
```

Comment: You're not storing the values anywhere. Store them somewhere and then you can make use of `sum()` and `len()` (and then you don't need `count`).

Comment: Sorry but I'm kind of confused now! where to store them and how would that be accomplished ?

Comment: I'd recommend a [`list`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/tutorial/introduction.html#lists).

Comment: You mean adding those numbers to a list by creating default value of an array[] then adding those values to the array with .append ?

Comment: Sounds like a good plan of action to me. Give it a shot.

Answer (score 2):

**Try this:**
After separating float values from the line, list them as shown and use a for loop to add those values and compute the average.
code:

```
fname = input("Enter file name:")
fh = open(fname)
count =0
number=[]
total=0
for line in fh:
    if not line.startswith("X-DSPAM-Confidence:"): 
        continue 
    #converting string to float  
    a=float(line[21:])
    #adding all the float values to a list
    number.append(a)    
    count =count+1
    total=0 
    #adding all the float values using a for loop
    for a in number: 
        total+=a     
        
avg = total/count
#to check if the numbers have been listed
print(number)
print(count)
print(total)
print("Average spam confidence:",avg)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
# Using Regular Expressions
from re import match

fname = raw_input("Enter file name: ")
if len(fname) == 0:
    fname = 'file.txt'
fh = open(fname)
count = 0
total = 0.0
for line in fh:
    # Regular expression looks for "For example", followed by whitespace,
    # followed by digits (1 or more), with a decimal point, followed by digits (1 or more)
    # with some extra possible characters for whatever else (ignored)
    m = match('For example\s+(\d+\.\d+).*', line)
    if m: # If there was a match, m will have an instance (rather than None)
        # m.group(1) holds the float number string
        total += float(m.group(1))
        count += 1

fh.close()
print "Count:",count
print "Total:",total
print "Average:", total/count
```

Comment: OK I'm getting this error :  http://i.gyazo.com/6fab15430447ab2468129647f4f5c930.png                         It looks like the line is not valid :      total += float(m.group(1))

Comment: Hmmm output some debug messages...
        print 'line: "%s" matches --> %s' % (line, m)
        print 'm.group(1) -->', m.group(1)
You should get output like:
    line: "For example   3.14156" --> <Match 0x238974>
    m.group(1) --> 3.14156

[edit]
I hate that I can't format these comments! (and I tried the formatting help guide)

Comment: Sorry but I didn't get what you mean !

Answer (score 0):

Edit: Ohh, now that you've [posted the file](http://www.pastebin.ca/3038306) in the comments, and explained that you're searching for the numbers a the end of the lines beginning with "X-DSPAM-Confidence:" it's much more clear what you're trying to do. This should do what you want now. Again, a simple solution avoiding regex.

The answer is in python3, but if you're using python2, just switch "input" to "raw_input" and remove the parenthesis from the print statements.

```
file_name = input("Enter file name: ") # If you're using python2, replace "input" with "raw_input"

numbers = []
# Use with instead of manually opening and closing files. It's safer.
with open(file_name, encoding = "utf-8") as f:
    for line in f:
      if line.startswith("X-DSPAM-Confidence:"):
            # If the number is always the last thing in the line, we can split the
            # line on whitespace and grab the last item from the resulting list.
            # Then convert the string to a float and append it to our list of
            # numbers.
            number = float(line.split()[-1])
            numbers.append(number)

# Get the average by dividing the sum of the numbers by the length of the list.
average = sum(numbers) / len(numbers)
print(average) # If you're using python2, get rid of the parenthesis.
```

If you're comfortable with list comprehensions, it can be even simpler:

```
file_name = input("Enter file name: ") # If you're using python2, replace "input" with "raw_input"

with open(file_name, encoding = "utf-8") as f:
    numbers = [float(line.split()[-1]) for line in f if line.startswith("X-DSPAM-Confidence:")]

average = sum(numbers) / len(numbers)
print(average) # If you're using python2, get rid of the parenthesis.
```

Comment: Thanks for you solution but I prefer if you have started from here :                    http://i.gyazo.com/31373bdbc83c7f421236bc94d323d653.png                      the float numbers are there and just need get the sum and count from them to produce the average ! Can that ?

Comment: Can you type up the text you want help extracting the floats from, or post it to http://pastebin.com/ or something? Call me lazy, but I don't really want to retype all the numbers in that screenshot ;)

Comment: That is the link of to the text file : http://www.pastebin.ca/3038306            The task is to  Write a program that prompts for a file name, then opens that file and reads through the file, looking for lines of the form:
X-DSPAM-Confidence:    0.8475
Count these lines and extract the floating point values from each of the lines and compute the average of those values and produce an output as shown below.
You can download the sample data at http://www.pythonlearn.com/code/mbox-short.txt when you are testing below enter mbox-short.txt as the file name.

Comment: @Omar That makes it more clear what you want! Give my solution a try now, I've updated it based on that file. I get 0.7507185185185187 when I run it. Don't forget to mark as answered and upvote if it works for you ;)

Comment: Thanks Beebs, But I really need to go with solution from the beginning of my code up to  ( xx = float(x)  +/-) because with that code I got to this : http://i.gyazo.com/31373bdbc83c7f421236bc94d323d653.png  , from here  I need to get the average of those values!

Comment: Why do you need to use that exact approach? I'm trying to suggest a better approach, similar to @tigerhawkt3 if you need to use the exact code you have already posted, after print xx, add "total += xx" then, after the for loop is done, you can write "average = total/count". You also haven't closed the file, which is important. If you use a "with" statement, then the file will be closed automatically.

Comment: sorry again I'm doing a course in Python for beginners and this is one of the assignments that l have to finish, and the course online Python compiler would not accept my code if it's not meeting the lecture instruction ( which is not much helpful in my case) and different  solution from the one above won't be accepted !

Comment: I see. Did you try what I suggested in my previous comment? "total += xx" is the missing piece in your solution. Then, with a total and a count, you can calculate the average.

Comment: You're pretty close. You want "average = total/count" and "print average" to be outside the for loop (I.e. At the end and not indented). That way you will only print them once.

Comment: The average number still not matching : http://i.gyazo.com/ab4175b0566097febf1cfde8efb2421d.png  why is that ?

Comment: Your result is exactly half the desired result, which is because you are increasing the count twice each loop. You have "count += 1" and "count = count + 1". Those do the same thing, and you only want to do it once. Delete one of them.

Comment: You are the best, many thanks : http://i.gyazo.com/c9db2037ebd6ce47e763fdf52ba495d0.png

Answer (score 0):

```
fname = raw_input("Enter File Name:")
count = 0
a = 0
try:
    fh = open(fname)
except:
    print 'file doesnt exist:', fname
    exit()

for line in fh:
    if not line.startswith("X-DSPAM-Confidence:"):continue
    print line

    colpos = line.find(':')


    number = float(line[colpos+1:])
    count = count + 1
    print number
    a = a + number


average = a / count
print 'average:',average
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi hope this code solves your problem pretty simple via just using parsing operator

U can still find the position of the ":" using find() and change the slicing operator accordingly.

```
count = 0
total = 0`enter code here`
fname = raw_input("Enter file name: ")
fh = open(fname)
for line in fh:
    if line.startswith("X-DSPAM-Confidence:"):
        count = count+1
        total = total+float(line[20:26])
print "Average spam confidence:",total/count
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try this:

```
fh = open("mbox-short.txt",'r')

count=0
total=0
result=0

for line in fh:
    if not line.startswith("X-DSPAM-Confidence:") :continue
    count=count+1
    num=float(line[21:])
    total=num+total

result=total/count
print("Average spam confidence:",result)
```

This is the logic. Understand the three variables, `num`, `count`, `total` and `result`. Its just a simple code!

Answer (score 0):

```
cnt=0
total=0
final=0

fname = input("Enter file name: ")
fh = open(fname)

for line in fh:
    if not line.startswith("X-DSPAM-Confidence:") : 
        continue
    cnt=cnt+1
    #print(line.strip())
    sm=float(line.split(":")[1])
    #print(sm)
    total=total+sm
final=total/cnt
print("Average spam confidence:",final)
```